# How to use vuejs data property as html attribute

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create an accordion with bootstrap in vuejs using a card component in a loop. I want to use the id property of the command variable so that each card has its id so that when we click on a card, only this card will open and not all the cards. Here is my code:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card" v-for="commande in commandes.data" :key="commande.id">
     <div class="card-header" :id="commande.id">
        <h3 class="card-title">
           <button class="btn btn-link col-md-12" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              <div class="text-primary">{{commande.id}}</div>
           </button>
        </h3>
     </div>
     <!-- /.card-header -->
       <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" :aria-labelledby="commande.id" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
             <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody>                      
                   <tr v-for="(produit, index) in commande.produits" :key="index">
                      <td>{{produit.designation}}</td>
                      <td>{{produit.prix_vente}}</td>
                      <td>{{produit.pivot.quantite}}</td>
                      <td>{{produit.prix_vente*produit.pivot.quantite}}</td>                  
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
      <div class="card-footer">
         <pagination :data="commandes" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

But when I click on a card, all the others open. it seems that this is due to the `data-target` attribute of the `<button>` tag of the `card-header` and the `attribute id` of the `<div>` which contains the `card-body`. I can't put a variable in the `data-target` attribute. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Vue data properties as HTML Attribute, just put a ":" in front of it.

```
<div :id="name_of_data_property">
```